# Конвертация даты в кол-во дней

Tags: javascript

Есть json объект который возвращает нам такую дату:

```
2021-01-08 06:35:58.669496
```

Как с помощью javascript конвертировать эту дату а именно в (сколько прошло кол-во дней с текущей даты)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
const d = '2021-01-08 06:35:58.669496';
console.log((Date.now() - Date.parse(d)) / (1000 * 3600 * 24))
```

Answer (score 1):

Самый простой способ, который обрабатывает даты вашего типа -

```
function calculate(date) {
    date = date.split(' '); // разделяем строку на дату и время
    date = date[0] + 'T' + date[1] + 'Z'; // собираем новую
    let ms = (new Date() - new Date(date)); //вычисляем количество миллисекунд
    let sec = ms / 1000; // вычисляем кол-во секунд
    return  sec / 86400; //возвращаем кол-во дней в float типе, если надо в int - то добавляем parseInt
}
console.log(calculate('2021-01-08 06:35:58.669496'));
```